# using the Greatest Common Divisor to find an integer.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I answered a question in my HW sheet and the last question was:

Let *g* be the greatest common divisor of 9883529 and 759345. Find g
using Euclid's Algorithm and find integers x and y so that *g* =
9883529*x* + 759345*y*.

Using the algorithm I have found that the GCD between those two int's was 1.

What I'm wondering is how do I find the integers x and y and is it correct that the GCD is in fact 1.

Comment: Just run the algorithm backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the $GCD$ is $1$. At each step, you simply keep track of the operation you did to reduce the size of each number. Let $m=9883529$ and $n=759345$. Let's denote the $GCD$ of $m,n$ by $(m,n)$. Then, since
$9883529=13×759345+12044$ we have
$$(m,n)=(9883529,759345),$$
$$(n,m-13n)=(759345,12044).$$
Continue likewise and you'll eventually find integers $x,y$ such that $xm+yn=1$

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the help. Also I found an identical question asked by someone (probably using the same text book I am, should I keep this question open?)

Comment: No problems. Not sure about what to do in that case!

Comment: By any chance have you worked out what x and y are mean't to be? After going through the steps twice, I got the same numbers but don't end up adding 1 for xm + ym = 1.

Comment: $9883529\times 690434 -759345\times  8986593=1$